# Finding an equation for the plane passing through 3 points

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Let $\displaystyle \mathbf{r}_{1}=x_{1} \mathbf{i}+y_{1} \mathbf{j}+z_{1} \mathbf{k}, \,\mathbf{r}_{2}=x_{2} \mathbf{i}+ y_{2} \mathbf{j}+z_{2} \mathbf{k} \,\text{and}\,\mathbf{r}_{3}=x_{3} \mathbf{i}+y_{3} \mathbf{j}+z_{3} \mathbf{k}$ be the position vectors of points $\displaystyle P_{1}\left(x_{1}, y_{1}, z_{1}\right), \,P_{2}\left(x_{2}, y_{2}, z_{2}\right)$ and $\displaystyle P_{3}\left(x_{3}, y_{3}, z_{3}\right) .$ Find an equation for the plane passing
through $P_{1}, \,P_{2}$ and $P_{3}$. See figure on the right

[image]

---

I have a problem. Actually I know how I can solve that because it is so long if I use normal solution. Do you know more short solution or other method for this question ?
Can you help me ?

Comment: More short or other than what? What is your “normal” solution?

Comment: @MartinR I mean , When I take matris of  ... P1P2 (vector) x P1P3(vector) ....

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide all relevant information. Post your problem (and your current solution) as *text* (preferably MathJax formatted) and not as an image.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation of the plane is
$$x_n x + y_n y + z_n z = d$$

The direct method is to solve
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
x_n x_1 + y_n y_1 + z_n z_1 &= d \\
x_n x_2 + y_n y_2 + z_n z_2 &= d \\
x_n x_3 + y_n y_3 + z_n z_3 &= d \\
\end{aligned} ~ \right . \tag{1}\label{1}$$
Although there are three equations and four unknowns, this is directly solvable.

The traditional method is to exploit the fact that vectors $(x_2 - x_1, y_2 - y_1, z_2 - z_1)$ and $(x_3 - x_1, y_3 - y_1, z_3 - z_1)$ are tangential to the plane.  Their cross product is normal to both, and therefore normal to the plane, and is suitable as the normal $(x_n, y_n, z_n)$.  Therefore,
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
x_n &= (y_2 - y_1)(z_3 - z_1) - (z_2 - z_1)(y_3 - y_1) \\
y_n &= (z_2 - z_1)(x_3 - x_1) - (x_2 - x_1)(z_3 - z_1) \\
z_n &= (x_2 - x_1)(y_3 - y_1) - (y_2 - y_1)(x_3 - x_1) \\
d &= x_n x_1 + y_n y_1 + z_n z_1 \\
~ &= x_n x_2 + y_n y_2 + z_n z_2 \\
~ &= x_n x_3 + y_n y_3 + z_n z_3 \\
\end{aligned} \right . \tag{2}\label{2}$$
where any one of the three equations for $d$ can be used.

The traditional method requires nine multiplications, nine subtractions, and six additions.  I don't see why one would call that "not short", when dealing with 3D vector algebra.